# Latex drawing of the following screen shot

Tags: tex-core, tkz-graph

Can anyone help with the drawing of this pic in latex?

I have included what I have done:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in} 
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.51in}

%\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}


 %\linespread{1.5}
\newcommand\answerbox{%%
    \fbox{\rule{1in}{0pt}\rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{4ex}}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}

\pagestyle{empty}
    %
 \tikzstyle{int}=[draw, fill=white!20, minimum size=4em]

  \tikzstyle{init} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm,auto,>=latex']

    \node [int,align=center] (a) {$ f \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x_1,x_2, \cdots,x_n]$\\Black Box $ \mathbf{B}$}; 
   
    \draw[<-] ([yshift=5pt]a.west)  -- node[above]{$\alpha$} ++(-4em,0em);  ++(4em,0em);   
    \draw[->] ([yshift=5pt]a.east) -- node[above]{$f(\alpha)\mod p$} ++(8em,0em); 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site, which is why you received a downvote. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is totally unclean! This is for you reference.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,inner xsep=5mm,inner ysep=20mm] (a) {$f(x_1,x_2, \cdots,x_n) \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x_1,x_2, \cdots,x_n]$}; 
\draw[->] (a.east)--+(3,0)  node[midway,above]{$f(\alpha)\mod p$}; 
\draw[<-] (a.north)--+(0,2) node[midway,right]{$p$}; 
\def\d{.75}
\draw[<-] (a.west)++(0,2*\d)--+(-2,0) node[midway,above]{$\alpha_1$};   
\draw[<-] (a.west)++(0,\d)--+(-2,0) node[midway,above]{$\alpha_2$};   
\draw[<-] (a.west)--+(-2,0) node[midway,above]{$\alpha_3$};   
\draw (a.west)+(-1,-\d+.2) node{$\vdots$};   
\draw[<-] (a.west)++(0,-2*\d)--+(-2,0) node[midway,above]{$\alpha_n$};   
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```